# Всем привет кто подскажет как оптимизировать сайт. Opencart 2.3

Tags: оптимизация, opencart, оптимизация-сайтов

[Вот сайт](http://partsua.com.ua/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51) после добавления 4500 товаров стал зависать в просмотрах отдельного товара. Какие есть идеи по решению этой проблемы, возможно кто-то уже сталкивался.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Нанять специализирующихся на этом людей - по-моему оптимальное решение. Серьёзно, описание оптимизации тут займёт четыре экрана, при этом надо не забывать, что это чья-то профориентация.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Comment: Отключите модуль "случайные товары" в карте товара. проверьте